# php mailer problem while sending the mail with pdf

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

so i want to send mail with pdf when someones sends it. my code was working some time ago but it stopped working suddenly and idk what exactly happened which caused it to do so. ill be attaching the code here please tell me what exactly needs to be changes.

**and why exactly it stopped working suddenly.**

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
// $email = $_POST["email"];
$Position = $_POST["Position"];
$LinkedIn = $_POST["LinkedIn"];
$Contact = $_POST["Contact"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$Subject = "Mail from" . $fname . " " . $lname . ". Position: " . $Position;

$Body = "";
$Body .= "First Name: ";
$Body .= $fname;
$Body .= "\n <br>";
$Body .= "\nLast Name: ";
$Body .= $lname;
$Body .= "\n <br> ";
$Body .= "\nEmail: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n <br>";
$Body .= "\nMessage: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n <br>";
$Body .= "\nPosition: ";
$Body .= $Position;
// $Body .= "\n <br>";
// $Body .= "\nResume: ";
// $Body .= $resume;
$Body .= "\n <br>";
$Body .= "\nPhone no: ";
$Body .= $Contact;

try {

    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'mail id';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom('theaakashdevsops@gmail.com', 'aaka');

    $mail->addAddress($email);

    if ($_FILES['attachment']['name'] != null) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], "uploads/{$_FILES['attachment']['name']}")) {
            // $mail->addAttachment("uploads/{$_FILES['attachment']['name']}");

            $mail->AddAttachment("uploads/{$_FILES['attachment']['name']}", "{$_FILES['attachment']['name']}");

        }

    }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->Body = $Body;
    // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    // echo '<script>window.location.href="index.php?message_sent";</script>';
    // header("Location: sent.html");
    echo header("Location: sent.html");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo header("Location: not sent.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Akash please attach the exact error that you received

Comment: enable your smtp debug for mailer. get exact issue what is happening. attach allow in question

Comment: What changed when it stopped working? Did the Gmail sending requirements change on the same day, for example? Does you code think that it's sent the mail?

Comment: If it suddenly stopped working but you didn't change the code, then the answer is more likely to be in the debug logs than the code itself. Have a look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Please provide the error that you have found in the logs.